# MS Access - Updating Combobox Selection after another Combobox's Selection in Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a combobox in a form called VendorName under a Form. Under a table, I have inserted VendorCurrency in each entry for vendors. Now what I want to do is once the VendorName in the form is chosen, I want the QuotationCurrency combobox to update and select the respective VendorCurrency .

Note that I have another table called Currency, holding all currencies and I use them as Row Source for the combobox QuotationCurrency.

I had written vba script as follows but it didn't work. What should I do?

```
Private Sub VendorName_AfterUpdate()
Me.QuotationCurrency = DLookup("VendorCurrency", "Vendor", "VendorName = 'Me!VendorName '")
Me.QuotationCurrency.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Concatenate* the name value:

```vb
Private Sub VendorName_AfterUpdate()
    
    Me!QuotationCurrency.Value = DLookup("VendorCurrency", "Vendor", "VendorName = '" & Me!VendorName.Value & "'")

End Sub
```

A requery shouldn't be needed if the rowsource is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, VendorName is combobox with default value `VendorId`.
Try

```
Private Sub VendorName_AfterUpdate()
Me.QuotationCurrency.Value = DLookup("VendorCurrency" _ 
           , "Vendor", "VendorId = " & cstr(Me!VendorName.Value))
End Sub
```

Comment: It didn't work, showing run-time error 3075 - syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'VendorID = xxxxx'

Comment: Is ``VendorId`` type - number?

Comment: Yes it is number, but I want to show Vendor which is word